# Creating a root unit in DHIS 2

Tags: dhis2

I installed [DHIS 2](https://www.dhis2.org/) without the sample data and I don't know how to create a root unit. Could you tell me how to create a root unit?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean a root organisation unit? You can do that from the organisation unit app:

Organisation Units app `->` Organisation Unit `->` `Add new` button in the upper right corner.

The first organisation unit you create will be the root of the organisation unit tree.

However I would recommend using the Sierra Leone demo database from https://www.dhis2.org/downloads (under "sample data") to get to know DHIS if you're new to it. Setting up DHIS from scratch can be a lot of work.